# How to setup up multiple entries in Gulp for webpack-stream?

Tags: webpack, gulp, webpack-stream

The documentation for webpack-stream gives the following as a guide for setting up multiple entry points.  My question is what is 'src/entry.js' in this case? How is it used? How is it different from what is defined in the webpack entry section?

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const webpack = require('webpack-stream');
gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/entry.js')
    .pipe(webpack({
      entry: {
        app: 'src/app.js',
        test: 'test/test.js',
      },
      output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
      },
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**return gulp.src('src/entry.js')** - Creates a stream for reading Vinyl objects from the file system. [link-1](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src/), [Link-2](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/explaining-globs)
In other words, you are returning the **entry.js** file from your **src/** folder.
Next **.pipe** - here you perform various file conversions. [link](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/using-plugins)

What is the difference I cannot say.
For these tasks I use TerserJs.
I've adapted it for gulp if you're interested in using it. You can use [this code](https://github.com/terser/terser/pull/1035/files).